# Upper bound on an expression raised to the nth power

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Consider the expression, where $x \gg n$.

\begin{equation}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}.
\end{equation}

I am trying to find an upper bound of this expression. Can an upper bound be

\begin{equation}
1 + \frac{\text{poly}(n)}{x}?
\end{equation}

I have the intuition that the higher order terms should all be suppressed, but I was looking for a short proof of this fact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n}=e^{n\log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)}\le e^{\frac n x}$$

then we could use for example that for $0<y< 1.25$

$$e^y\le1+2y \implies \left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n} \le 1+\frac {2n} x$$

More in general it can be shown that for any $\varepsilon >0$ such that $0<\frac x n <\varepsilon$ we can find $a>1$ such that

$$\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n} \le 1+\frac {an} x$$

Comment: Very nice answers.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastiano! Maybe we can also found other ways to solve it. Bye